# iOS5 Custom Window rotation issue

Tags: ios, window, alert

So I'm creating and showing a custom window in my iOS app because I'm writing a dynamic alert view that also functions like a growl/toast alert.  It works AWESOMELY in ios6 (Hopefully I can open source this baby and you can all check it out)

But anyway, when I run this in ios5, the window that my alerts exist on doesn't seem to rotate with the device/simulator.  No matter what, my custom window stays in portrait mode.

The UIWindow is just a UIView subclass, so there's no nice 'shouldRotate' delegate method.

I'm kinda stumped on why this is happening in ios5 but not 6.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 1):

My window has a rootviewcontroller, which I completely forgot about.  I just needed to implement

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}
```

To get it to work.

:-D

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not recommended two use multiple instances of `UIWindow` in one iOS app. The only valid reason to do so is to support external screens. You should use a `UIView` instead, ideally managed by a `UIViewController`.

I assume, (since you didn't provide any code, I can only assume) the reason why your window doesn't 'rotate' is, that it's simply not getting any notifications about device rotation. Only the `keyWindow` receives them by default.

I would highly recommend to redesign your app to use a properly managed `UIView` instead. If you desperately don't want that for some reason, you would have to register your instance of `UIWindow` to receive the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` and then (in the handler) evaluate what the new orientation is and change the window's frame accordingly (plus maybe other things that need to be done in response to the orientation change)

Comment: So the reason I'm using a window is because we're writing our own custom alerts and growl messages.  We need it to pop up over the keyboard and everything, and UIWindow is the perfect tool for this (.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert :D)

So, yes, it's not recommended, but to accomplish what we're trying to do, I have to.  My alerts are cool though in that you can show it in a view or in this new custom window :-D  And, everything works GREAT in ios6, I don't get why ios5 would break.

I'll look into registering for rotation events in custom windows.